# Adding an item in existing frameWork setting option list android

Tags: android, android-framework

Hie all, 
I created one homeScreen Application and it working fine for me . one thing what i am seeing is every time i click on the HOME button it list me the native home application and the third party application which i installed in it . the below figure explains the context [image: list of home applications]

this is somewhat an extra work to user to select the home screen every time he presses the home screen. so what i was thinking is that to give the option for user in the settings->display seetings-> so that he can choose the application which he want .[image: setting menu]

as i ve access to complete android file system and i can create my own image and test in the development boards . The problem here is i am unable to add item to the existing settings code . or u can suggest me the other solution. i tried with the Display settings class in mydroid.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not change system settings (i.e. alter the menu) via code on normal (non-rooted) Android devices.
2. User can set the default action by ticking "Use by default for this action." on selector screen. From then on  user will not be asked to select the action, instead the default action will be invoked.

Comment: hi peter , i selected the native application for the "Use by default for this action."  after doing this i am unable to launch the other applications only . i mean how do i disable it???

Comment: i got it ... i reset the phone so now able to do see the third party home screen application.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Applications, then select the your application. Scroll down and select 'Clear Defaults.'

Comment: i have android file system with me .. i want to run the native applications by doing some minor changes but i am getting error if i try to run those applications.Native applications like launcher , contacts , calender and all ...  so can u jus tell me how to run those applications ??